# Using css border property in eclipse rcp application

Tags: java, css, eclipse-rcp

I am currently working on an eclipse rcp application that we want to customize look-and-feel wise via CSS.

Sadly the documentation is not that great, so I'd like to try to get help here.

I would like to configure the border of several Widgets via CSS. For example `Composite` or `ScrolledComposite`.

The CSS Theme is working generally, this question is only about the border property.

Can I use the border property at all to configure the border of an Widget or is there only the `SWT.BORDER` property that needs to be set in the creation process of a widget?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for borders in the SWT CSS. The SWT.BORDER style on the control constructor is the only thing available.

You can write your own CSS property handlers using the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.propertyHandler` extension point, but adding a border would be difficult as the SWT controls don't support it.

All the existing CSS properties are defined using the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.propertyHandler` extension point, mostly in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt` plugin.